# Stability of pyridine derivatives

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds, stability

> Arrange the following pyridine derivatives in the order of increasing stability
> of adduct formed with $\ce{BBr3}.$ Explain briefly.
>
> [image: I: 3‐methylpyridine; II: 2‐methylpyridine; III: 3,5‐dimethylpyridine]

I'm pretty confused about which structure is the most stable. I'd say structure **III** is the most stable as it has two methyl groups to donate electrons to nitrogen and increase its Lewis basicity.

However, I think **III** may not be the most stable because of steric hindrance. In fact, structure **II** could be the most stable as the methyl group is closer to nitrogen and there's no steric hindrance. Therefore, the answer should be **III** < **I** < **II**.

Is my reasoning correct? Are there any factors to consider for stability?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the order of stability is **II** > **III** > **I**. The adduct should be formed between the lone pair on nitrogen and the Lewis acid. From there, I would apply the M+, I+ effects of the methyl groups as are known from benzene derivatives (although the substitution chemistry of pyridine is different from benzene).

Comment: I see. Just clarifying, does the distance between N and the methyl group play a part in stability? If the methyl group is closer to N, it'd be easier for N to receive electrons from the methyl group, hence higher lewis basicity. I'm not sure if it's a misconception.

Comment: I think it is a misconception, take a look at the mechanism of the aromatic electrophilic substitution on benzene, toluene/phenol, and nitro-benzene. I think the same concepts apply here.